# Is it possible for the polygon to have different nodes have different data?

Tags: nft, web3j, polygon

I use the eth_log to get the event of nft contract on polygon, and if found that some token id data lost. But when i rescan it after some hours , the event data is full.
so i doubt that is it possible for the polygon to have different nodes whit the same block height,but they have the different data.
the code of get event by eth_log,i already duplicate check last 12 blocks,but still lost data:
[why the tokenId is lost when the eth_log method](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140741/why-the-tokenid-is-lost-when-the-eth-log-method)

I asked same question to OpenAI,and this is the answer:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is, the OpenAI seems have answer you why, but anymore you want to know? any more question detail?

> sorry for answer for I can't comment still.if no help you can delete it.

Comment: now i use the ankr  rpcUrRL to get event by eth_log, the ankr is a rpc server,and it has many nodes.  and seems that it lost some data. is't caused by different node with different data. but when i rescan these blockheight after few hours, the data is full.
my code in this question : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140741/why-the-tokenid-is-lost-when-the-eth-log-method

how many blocks should i delay。it seems 12 block not work

Comment: Delays are normal .